# Laravel error : Trying to get property of non-object in show.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

My code is here if you want any other section of code, i will provide also that piece of code

```
 <div class="panel-heading ">Organization Profile</div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Attributes</th>
      <th>Values</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Org Name</td>
      <td>{{$org->name}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Owner Name</td>
      <td>{{$org->owner}}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: i am beginner, experts please guide me !

Comment: What's the code in the controller?

Comment: it is obviously $org is not what you want

Comment: $org is null, find out why

Comment: Show controller only then one can tell

Comment: my controller code section is here

   public function show($id)
    {
        $org = Organization::find($id);
        // $data = ['org', $id];
        return view('Admin.organizations.show',compact('org'));
    }

Comment: If those attributes are supposed to be nullable then add a default value. For example, <td>{{$org->name ?? ''}}</td>

Comment: #Dave Carruthers i have entered data in the particular table, do you want to see ?

Comment: when you call show.blade.php you have to pass in the $org variable. That should be done in the controller with something like
return view('show')->with(compact('org'));
That's where the code is that we need to also see.

Comment: #Daniel Dale I did this [ return view('show')->with(compact('org')); ] but still the error exists, help me to fix this

Comment: @WaseemAfzal Can you edit your question and include the code from that section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trying to get property of non-object` issue usually comes in Laravel when you are returning array but try using object in your blade file or not passing the correct object string at all.

I notice from comments that you are passing `$orgs`, not `$org` in the function.

```
public function create() { 
    return view('Admin.organizations.create',compact('orgs')); 
}
```

Update your blade file like below:

```
<div class="panel-heading ">Organization Profile</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Attributes</th>
  <th>Values</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Org Name</td>
  <td>{{$orgs->name}}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Owner Name</td>
  <td>{{$orgs->owner}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering all the comments, you should probably have something like this in your controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
 $org = Organization::find($id);
 // $data = ['org', $id];
 return view('Admin.organizations.show')->with(compact('org'));
}
```

and this is your blade view:

```
<div class="panel-heading ">Organization Profile</div>
 @if (empty($org))
    <h1>Organization is empty</h1>
 @else 
    <table class="table table-striped">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Attributes</th>
         <th>Values</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>Org Name</td>
         <td>{{$org->name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Owner Name</td>
         <td>{{$org->owner}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
 @endif
</div>
```

Of course not knowing what is in the Organization model would keep us from knowing whether owner and name exist as properties of the model.